# If condition PHP using Unix Time

Tags: php, sql

Currently having an issue with a conditional statement in my social media site concerning unix time comparison to value in sql database. The following code is being used to apply a css statement on a class:

```
<?php 
if ($wo['story']['time'] < time() - 14400) {
?>

<style>
.breaks{ display: none important;}
</style>
<?php } ?>

 <?php if($wo['story']['publisher']['vericon'] == 1) { ?>
 <style>
 .blink{
    animation: blink 3s linear infinite;
    }
@keyframes blink{
0%{opacity: 1;}
50%{opacity: .25;}
100%{opacity: 1;}
}
</style>
              <div class="blink breaks" id="breaking" data-page="page" data-id="<?php echo $wo['page_profile']['page_id'];?>" style="width: 50%; padding: 5px; background: #462178; border-radius: 6px; color: #fff; margin-top: 3px;"><b>BREAKING</b> <div style="background: #fff; float: right; border-radius: 6px;"><span style="color: #333; padding: 3px;"><?php echo Wo_Time_Elapsed_String($wo['story']['time']); ?><span></div></div>
<?php } ?>
```

The first statement to apply display: none does not work, and the value in the database is unix time, but uses INT as a field type. I have echoed both the field and time() and compared, but it is failing to apply the class.

Comment: It would be better to make this comparison in the SQL rather than in PHP. What actually is your issue?

Comment: Please show your SQL data and your SQL table structure.

Comment: `$wo['story']['time']` Show what this value actually is and explain what you expect this value to be.

Comment: Not sure but probably `if (strtotime($wo['story']['time']) < (time() - 14400)) {`

Comment: 35 time   Index int(11)

Comment: https://www.mumblit.com/tim.png

Comment: sorry https://www.mumblit.com/tim.PNG

Comment: The purpose here is so that if the current unix time is 4 hours after the time field then do not display the div.

Comment: This is what currently displays and is way after 4 hour window. https://www.mumblit.com/time2.PNG